# TFS Website Build -> The type or namespace name 'something_ascx' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP'

Tags: asp.net, tfs, msbuild

Hello
I'm trying to build a website using Team Build 2010 (TFS and stuff), but it gives me this error:

The type or namespace name 'something_ascx' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

As I went to google, I found out that ASP is a 'pseudo' namespace which can't be referenced while compiling... but what I am supposed to do to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your program builds locally? What about if you get latest version on a new machine? You may forget to check-in/update something.

Answer (score 1):

dlls are not checked-in by default so if your building the application after several user check-ins, the dlls must be manually synchronized. I usully create a shared folder and add all the applications dlls there so that all users have the same version of them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand, I have a shared folder with all my app dlls, but I have no idea how this works regarding asp controls... Do I really need to manually synchronize App_Web_name-of-the-control.ascx.dll whenever anyone changes anything on it ? It'd be better if I had another way to reference controls, as copying dozens of dlls everytime seems ugly.